# Reliability and Performance Monitor for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, performance, display

Is there anything like [Reliability and Performance Monitor](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/winvista_ff_rmon.asp) for WinXP out there?

Anything that is actually worth using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Anvir Task Manager Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free.shtml)** works with Windows XP

[image]

It gives you detailed information about every process that is running, and about applications running automatically on Windows startup including all hidden applications.

Main features:

- Get full list of applications running automatically on Windows startup including all hidden applications.
- Get all additional information about startup applications.
- Disable/enable, add/delete, edit startup entries.
- Stop or run once again startup application.
- See alert when any new application adds itself to startup.
- Forbid some applications to be added to startup.
- See alert when Internet Explorer home page was changed.
- Get full information about all processes: CPU and memory usage, executable name with full path, priority, work time, user name.
- Get executable file properties, icon and version information.
- Stop many processes with one click.
- Change process priorities.
- Get current information about CPU usage including list of most active programs.
- Get current information about HDD usage.
- Detection and destruction of most propagated viruses.
- Virus database update.
- Minimum usage of system resources.

A [portable version](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm) is available.

---

**[Moo0 SystemMonitor](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/%23SystemMonitor)** lets you keep your eye on system resource usages of your PC. It currently supports 36 kinds of information including CPU, Memory, Network, and detailed HDD usages. Using this software, you may discover what is limiting your system performance in each occasion.

[image]

*Moo0 SystemMonitor is freeware, a portable version is available.*